# How to implement a "replacement" for initializer_list for vectors for compilers that does not support it?

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list, uniform-initialization

I use windows 7 and VS express 2012. The problem is that the compiler (which is the original compiler) does not support initializer_list for vectors. The class initializer_list does neither seem to be supported since `include<initializer_list>` gives an error.

What I want to do is to create something can define a vector using the same syntax as the initializer_list for vector. I have tried to search the web for a solution, but have not found one. The most questions are about creating an initializer_list class, which IMO seems to be tedious if not even impossible. The implementation does not need to use an initializer_list, the only thing I want is that the syntax is the same. I would also accept an alternative with equally simple syntax (but not a method that requires to create an array and pass to a function and so).

I am sorry that I cannot provide any code, but I am not sure where to start. This seems to be a hot topic, so the question should also be quite general.

Comment: If someone have a suggetsion to a better title, please comment or edit.

Comment: *"What I want to do is to create something can define a vector using the same syntax as the initializer_list for vector."* I think this is not possible. There is [`boost.assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html), which tries to create a convenient syntax for initialization, but it is not the same as C++11 uniform initialization.

Comment: You can't. The whole `initializer_list` business requires lots of compiler support. The best you can do is something along the lines of [`Boost.Assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

Comment: @T.C. Ok in that case I think that I can handle it. This is widely documented on the web. Thank you for the answer. It you want you can put it as an answer and get an accept.